# Android.mk - How to assemble and link ARM assembler files

Tags: android, gcc, assembly, android-ndk

I have some *.cpp source files and some *.s ARM assembler files I want to assemble and link in my Android.mk file (by running ndk-build script).

My Android.mk file looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE    := libTestJNI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Test.cpp TestAS_gas4.s 
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFPM_ARM -ffast-math -O3 -DOPT_ARM
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Unfortunately the *.s file is not recognized. ndk-build says:

```
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
make: *** No rule to make target `/cygdrive/c/projects/TestAS_gas4.s', needed by `/cygdrive/c/projects/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/libTestJNI/TestAS_gas4.o'.  Stop.
```

In a "normal" makefile I would have to assemble by using "as" in a rule. How is it done in the Android.mk files?

/Kim

Answer (score 5):

This is embarrasing but the problem was that the *.s files where located in a subfolder. The "No rule to make target" error is a very poor error description in this case.

/Kim

Comment: don't sweat the embarrassment.  We all do such things from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

hint: change suffixes :

```
ln -fs %.s %.S.arm
```